# Initialize object in AppDelegate from other class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have an Object in my AppDelegate declared:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) Object *object;
```

Now i want to initialize this Object in another class..I already tried it this way:

```
[[[[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]object] alloc]init];
```

But that´s not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
AppDelegate *objApp=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
objApp.object=[[Object alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple problems in your code.

First of all, `alloc` is not an instance method, but a class method. The correct way to alloc/init an object is the following :

```
Object *object = [[Object alloc] init];
```

Then you can use this code to get a reference to the application's delegate object :

```
((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

Where `AppDelegate` should be the name of your app's delegate class.

You can then do the following :

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appdelegate.object = [[Object alloc] init];
```

Your object will be allocated and initialized properly.

Answer (score -1):

use like this

```
AppDelegate *objectInAnotherClass = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] object];

objectInAnotherClass.object = [[Object alloc]init];
```

Answer (score -1):

First you import the `AppDelegate` on which class you have to call that global method.

and call using `AppDelegate` object.

```
AppDelegate *objApp=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
objApp.object=[[Object alloc]init];
```